# Java RegEx Replacement

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to input a String that contains a single `*` character, then a second String. The `*` will be replaced by the second String.

Since the `private static String first` can not put in the `public static void main(String[] args) {}`, how do I do the replacement of putting second String in the first String?

```
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Main {
    private static String a = "*";
    private static String first = first;
    System.out.println("Enter the first String: ");
    String first = scan.nextLine();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first String: ");
        String first = scan.nextLine();


        //Second
        System.out.println("Enter the replacement String: ");
        String second = scan.nextLine();
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(a);
        Matcher m = p.matcher(first);
        first = m.replaceAll(second);
        System.out.println(first);
```

Comment: how are you printing outside of the method?

Comment: This question isn't about string replacement via regular expression as much as it's about how classes work and how they should be set up. I would suggest reading a book on Java or perhaps going through [Oracle's Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use pattern and matcher here, just plain `String#replaceAll` method, read about it [at the javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), as:

```
String a = "\\*";
first = first.replaceAll(a, second);
```

You just need to escape the `*` sign, since it is used as regex.

Just to be clear, you can declare and initialize a variables out of the main method, but with the predefined values. If you need to initialize a variable via user's input, you have to move your initialization into method's body.

Comment: Hopefully OP will never instantiate an object of type `Main`, that is if OP's code will even compile. There are a lot more issues than RegEx going on here.

Comment: @JonnyHenly yep, I just hope, it's a formatting issue during post creation, not the real code OP has

Comment: You might be right, I hadn't noticed that the last couple of lines of OP's class members matched the first three lines of OP's `main` method.